# The last number is being cut off in my sum total on the status bar

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I highlight some cells and want to get a quick SUM that shows on the status bar, the last digit in the # is being cut off.  This just started happening recently.  How can I fix that so that the entire # shows?

Comment: How large is the number?  Is it more than 15 digits?

Comment: Try to extend cells.

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click on the bar where Sum appears, you can unselect some of the other functions which should realise you some more real estate.

Comment: At least in Excel 2013, no matter how small I make the window, the `SUM: 1000000006` piece will either be complete, or it will completely go away. I can't get it to cut off one or more digits. Unless Glenna's situation is quite different, I don't think unselecting other items will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try right-clicking the status bar, then un-selecting and re-selecting the functions in the order of rightmost displayed first to leftmost. For example, on my system this order is `Sum`, `Max`, `Min`, `Numerical Count`, `Count`, then `Average`. This seems to force the summary statistics to redraw with enough space for all the digits to show up.